# Enemy health bar and taking damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have added the following script to my enemies for the purpose of having a health bar:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Enemy_Health : MonoBehaviour {

    public float health;
    public float maxHealth;

    public GameObject healthBarUI;
    public Slider slider;

    private void Start()
    {
        health = maxHealth;
        slider.value = calculateHealth();

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        slider.value = calculateHealth();
        if (health < maxHealth)
        {
            healthBarUI.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if (health > maxHealth)
        {
            health = maxHealth;
        }
    }
    float calculateHealth()
    {
        return health / maxHealth;
    }
}
```

It is working well. However, my player has a weapon (axe) and I would like when my player attacks using the weapon, the health bar of the enemy decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function that decreases the health of enemy on attack. Something like this:

```
public void DecreaseHealth(healthamount)
{
    health -= healthamount;
}
```

Call this function in your player script with the exact health you want to decrease on attack.

Comment: I have multiple enemies with multiple health bars, can  i use your answer?

Comment: I gave my answer based on the script you provided. I don't know your code structure but the basic concept is same, like this code. If it fits in your structure then you can use it.

Comment: @Tito When your player attacks, use `Physics` to find the enemy that they are attacking (if any) and call `GetComponen<Enemy_Health>()` to get a reference to that enemy's health script. You can then call `DecreaseHealth` on it.